# insert query is not working in my program but working well at mysql tab

Tags: php, mysql, insert

my sql insert query is not working in my program. I have print the query and then copy paste that code in mysql tab of the phpmyadmin, then it works perfectly. Any body please help me.

```
if ($_FILES["thumbnailimage"]["size"]>0 )
{
    $thumbnailkey = generateUniqueKey($tbl_uploads,"upload_key",12);
    $fkey = generateUniqueKey($tbl_uploads,"file_key",24);
    $folderkey = generateUniqueKey($tbl_uploads,"folderkey",28);
    $fname = substr($_FILES['thumbnailimage']['name'],0,strpos($_FILES['thumbnailimage']['name'],"."));
    $ext = getExtension($_FILES['thumbnailimage']['name']);
    $insertnewupload = "INSERT INTO ".$tbl_uploads." (upload_key,file_key,file_name,file_type,ext,folderkey,user_id,status,pkey) VALUES ";
    $insertnewupload.="('".$thumbnailkey."','".$fkey."','".$fname."','1','".$ext."','".$folderkey."','".$_SESSION['user_id']."','0','".$productkey."')";
    echo "<br>1=>".$insertnewupload;
//  $db->connect();
    $exec_insertnewitem = mysql_query($insertnewupload);
```

This is the printed out put

```
INSERT INTO tbl_uploads (upload_key,file_key,file_name,file_type,ext,folderkey,user_id,status,pkey) VALUES ('f958c38e5c31','9b6bd5118ec4a8456bcc46df','sunil','1','jpg','1c1a536fbdde4f24a219ada4c1c9','7','0','3b593aff92ce')
```

Comment: Please write error here you are getting in insert operation..

Comment: How did you find out it does not work in your program?

Comment: There is no error. Data is not inserted when I run the program.

Comment: I sure hope productKey can't be specified by the user, otherwise you might be in store for a nasty shock someday.  You really should be using parameterized queries or escaping the inputs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: no data inserted in the table , when I run the program

Comment: no productkey is already taken .

Comment: Please remember, I can run this query very well via the mysql tab of the phpmyadmin. But i can't run it fro my program. I thought it may be due to any connection existence problem ..

Comment: Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php to output errors that are happen.

Comment: If the problem is about the existence of a database connection, you need to post more information. There is nothing in the code above where a connection would be opened.

Answer (score 1):

You are quoting numeric values, you should aim for.  I've added backticks around the field names also (I can't recall if 'status' is reserved)

```
INSERT INTO `tbl_uploads` (
    `upload_key`,
    `file_key`,
    `file_name`,
    `file_type`,
    `ext`,
    `folderkey`,
    `user_id`,
    `status`,
    `pkey`
) 
VALUES (
    'f958c38e5c31',
    '9b6bd5118ec4a8456bcc46df',
    'sunil',
    '1',
    'jpg',
    '1c1a536fbdde4f24a219ada4c1c9',
    7,
    0,
    '3b593aff92ce'
)
```

So the following replacement for the line specifying values will suffice

```
$insertnewupload = "INSERT INTO `".$tbl_uploads."` (`upload_key`,`file_key`,`file_name`,`file_type`,`ext`,`folderkey`,`user_id`,`status`,`pkey`) VALUES ";
$insertnewupload.="('".$thumbnailkey."','".$fkey."','".$fname."','1','".$ext."','".$folderkey."',".$_SESSION['user_id'].",0,'".$productkey."')";
```

As an addition, there'll probably be a few comments stating you should be using mysqli_ functions or PDO instead of mysql_.  At present you're potentially vulnerable to SQL injection with such a method of making a query.

Answer (score 0):

Could be severy reasons... did you check that you connect to the correct database ? Maybe add the database name before "tbl_uploads", e.g. "mybase.tbl_uploads"

Answer (score 0):

Always make practice to write mysql query like this.

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO tablename (`upload_key`,`file_key`,`file_name`,`file_type`,`ext`,`folderkey`,`user_id`,`status,pkey`) VALUES ('f958c38e5c31','9b6bd5118ec4a8456bcc46df','sunil','1','jpg','1c1a536fbdde4f24a219ada4c1c9','7','0','3b593aff92ce')";
 $check = mysql_query($query);
```

check if var_dump($check);returns true or false..